# Searching for an easy way to pass in a variable through multiple functions

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm searching for an efficient way to pass input for the 'params' parameter into my python requests call for individual GET requests and I'm not sure if my approach would be overly complicated:

What I have now:

main.py

```
#Example1
module.endpoint1()
```

module.py

```
import requests

def requests_get(url, authstuff, params=None):
   request=(requests.get(url, params=params, authstuff)

def endpoint1():
   url=...
   return requests_get(url)

def endpoint2():
   url=...
   return requests_get(url)

def endpoint3():
   url=...
   return requests_get(url)

.....
```

What I will have once I make the 'params' parameter accessible in my main.py call:

main.py

```
#Example1
module.endpoint1(params=?functioncode)
```

module.py

```
import requests

def requests_get(url, authstuff, params=None):
   request=(requests.get(url, params=params, authstuff)

def endpoint1(params=None):
   url=...
   return requests_get(url, params)

def endpoint2(params=None):
   url=...
   return requests_get(url, params)

def endpoint3(params=None):
   url=...
   return requests_get(url, params)

.....
```

I'm not sure if this is an efficient means or if there is another route to take that would be simpler to access the secondary function call to 'requests_get'. I'd hate to have to specify the 'params=None' setting for each endpoint function because I have hundreds but would this pretty much be the only way to do it?

Comment: Please explain your downvotes

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I can understand why you have been. It is pretty hard to deduce what you are trying to do from the question and your example is not [Minimal, Complete or Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, `requests_get()` defined a positional arg after a keyword arg which is a `SyntaxError`. Fix that and then every one of your `endpoint*()` functions will raise a `TypeError` because they are missing the positional arg `authstuff`. Also, your `endpoint*()` functions accept `params` as an arg but don't pass that on to `requests_get()`.

Comment: Okay, so I corrected my function args and the variables passed to my second arg. My question though is whether I constructed an efficient way to pass my main params variable two functions deep to get it passed into my "requests.get" callout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the correct solution for this issue is to use an **arg or **kwarg parameter in your function definitions to pass into sub-functions.